# How to not encode special HTML characters in Swagger UI / SpringDoc

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I want to include an example in an OpenAPI spec that includes HTML special characters. How can I do that so that Swagger UI does not HTML encode it?

Or probably the more appropriate question:
How can I configure SpringDoc to not encode HTML characters?

YAML file:

```
foo:
  type: string
  example: '<bar baz="hello">world</foo>'
```

Expected display in the Swagger UI:

```
<foo>
  <bar baz="hello">world</foo>
</foo>
```

Actual display:

```
<foo>
  &lt;bar baz=&quot;hello&quot;&gt;world&lt;/foo&gt;
</foo>
```

Edit: Added an example of how it goes wrong (with an added bonus of an example being swallowed):

YAML:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: A title
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /collections:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A description
          content:
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/collection'
components:
  schemas:
    collection:
      description: A collection description
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          example: example ID
          xml:
            prefix: abc
            name: identifier
        location:
          type: object
          example: >
            <dct:Location>
              <dcat:bbox rdf:datatype="https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.geo+json">
                  {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
              </dcat:bbox>
              <locn:geometry rdf:datatype="https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.geo+json">
                  {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5, 6], [7, 8]]]}
              </locn:geometry>
            </dct:Location>
          properties:
            bbox:
              description: The bounding box of the dataset
              type: string
              # not possible with openapi as of April 2023
              # type: object
              # properties:
              #   typo:
              #     type: string
              #     example: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.geo+json
              #     xml:
              #       attribute: true
              #       prefix: rdf
              #       name: datatype
              xml:
                prefix: dcat
                name: bbox
            geometry:
              description: Describes the geometry of the dataset
              type: string
              # not possible with openapi as of April 2023
              # type: object
              # properties:
              #   typo:
              #     type: string
              #     example: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.geo+json
              #     xml:
              #       attribute: true
              #       prefix: rdf
              #       name: datatype
              xml:
                prefix: locn
                name: geometry
          xml:
            prefix: dct
            name: Location
      xml:
        prefix: abc
        name: Collection
```

Example output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:Collection>
&lt;dct:Location&gt;
  &lt;dcat:bbox rdf:datatype=&quot;https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.geo+json&quot;&gt;
      {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;LineString&quot;, &quot;coordinates&quot;: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
  &lt;/dcat:bbox&gt;
  &lt;locn:geometry rdf:datatype=&quot;https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.geo+json&quot;&gt;
      {&quot;type&quot;: &quot;Polygon&quot;, &quot;coordinates&quot;: [[[5, 6], [7, 8]]]}
  &lt;/locn:geometry&gt;
&lt;/dct:Location&gt;
</abc:Collection>
```

Test it in the Swagger Editor: https://editor.swagger.io/

Comment: Is that YAML file generated or are you defining it separately?  How is your springdoc configured?  How have you defined the example?  If you are configuring your api via annotations, can you please provide an annotation example?  Please see how to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if necessary.  As it is, I can't reproduce your issue in order to provide an answer.

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to change from `type: string` to `type: object`.